# Segmentation marks in MusicXML

Tags: musicxml, music-notation

I am looking for a way to put segmentation marks in a musicXML file, which can be read by software such as musescore.

Perhaps a large vertical line or a label above a note?

Any ideas on how to mark a note in a simple way?

I can write a lyric text. But it would be awesome to mark it like this: 
[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this for music theory / textbook-type stuff, or is this something you need in a score/part?

Comment: This is for a music analysis software I am developing for one my research projects.